# how to - sqoop export using view to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a table in hive and i have created a view for it. 
say for example

My table has the following fields

```
id | name | city | state | county | country
```

My view is like this  `Id | name | country`

Now i need to export those values **[ from view ]** to sql server 
How can i export data from hive to sql server using view 
Is there any way ?

and i have been exporting to sql using the

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXX;username=YYY;password=ZZZZZ;database=AdventureWorksDW" --table sqlg --export-dir /hive/datawarehouse/sql -m 1 -input-fields-terminated-by "^"
```

but now i need to export using **view**

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

My .csv files is like below in HDFS

```
1^hari^XX^xx^yy^zz
2^migi^na^na^na^na
```

But i need to load only

```
1^hari^zz
2^migi^na
```

into SQL table

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.2.182;username=sa;password=1timep;database=AdventureWorksDW" --table sqlg --export-dir /hive/datawarehouse/sql -m 1 -input-fields-terminated-by "^" --columns "Id,name,country" --update-key "Id"
```

Answer (score 0):

The same Sqoop command should work for both table and a view. Check the Sqoop documentation ([1](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1763751)) on the same.

Comment: Sqoop will run SQL on the view in MR and get the data. Why does the command need a table as a parameter?

Comment: come on man - see my original response - as I said the same Sqoop command works for table and view

Comment: Okay , See in the command we are specifying only file path "/hive/datawarehouse/sql " . My .cav file 6 filed with delimited "^" . But i need to load only three fields into SQL . Which means i need to load only Id | name | country into my sql table . How can i do this using the above command ah

Comment: I know well , If i run the above command all the fields , ( 6 fields) will be loaded right ? but i want to load only ( 3 fields )

Comment: Your reference is for sqoop import, yes it is documented that sqoop import supports views.  @Backtrack was asking about sqoop export. And no sqoop export does not work for views. At least it is not documented, and I have spin off a test case and tried to do sqoop export from a Hive view - it fails with "ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException" - might be a sqoop bug. So again, your reference is not relevant as that is for sqoop import.